# How do I get a list of tables from a Firebird database?

Tags: python, firebird, kinterbasdb

So I've got a couple of Firebird databases I need to convert. I've managed to connect to them using python code and the kinterbasdb library, but I can't find a way to get a list of all the tables in the database. Is there a command that will give me the table names?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Getting the list of tables is:

1. In isql: [`show tables;`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-show-tables)
2. As a normal query:

   ```sql
   SELECT a.RDB$RELATION_NAME
   FROM RDB$RELATIONS a
   WHERE COALESCE(RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG, 0) = 0 AND RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0
   ```

Comment: The second method worked, although I had to drop the Relation Type from the equation

Comment: @Beacon80 I use Firebird 2.5, this column isn't available in older versions (database structure versions); if you use Firebird 2.5 and don't have this column, you need to backup and restore the database.

Comment: The query by Brent Rowland works for older versions (my query without `RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0` also includes views).

Comment: `RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0` - shouldn't there also be a check for `NULL` not only zero ? I  think there is some ambiguity there, when you think about differesnt legacy engine and ODS versions

Comment: @Arioch'The Good point, IIRC, it should always be populated in 2.5 database, but I have been bitten by that before. Added a `COALESCE`...

Comment: If my memory serves me (not sure), it is NOT always populated when engine 2.5 opens ODS of 2.1 (AFAIR that is 11.1).

Answer (score 6):

I use:

```
SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATIONS
WHERE (RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG <> 1 OR RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL) AND RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL
ORDER BY RDB$RELATION_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use that :

```
select rdb$relation_name, rdb$description
  from rdb$relations
 where rdb$view_blr is null
   and (rdb$system_flag is null or rdb$system_flag = 0)
 order by 1;
```