# Connection with Firebird with isql-fb works, but not using PHP or Python

Tags: python, php, sql, firebird

I have a third-party application that is based on a Firebird database (version 3.0). For statistics and further processing of data, I was thinking of regularly copying the database to a Linux server and making all the data available there via a web interface (PHP/Laravel). Direct access to the database is not possible as data is also changed during processing. However, I am failing to access the database and would like some help.

System: Ubuntu Server 20.04 clean install, with Firebird 3.0 from apt sources in the standard installation, no changes to firebird.conf.
Access via isql-fb works, I can perform all queries with it.

```
$ isql-fb
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> connect DB.FDB user 'sysdba' password 'password';
Database: DB.FDB, User: SYSDBA
SQL> show tables;
     [list of all tables]
```

When I try to access via PHP or Python, I get a similar error message in both cases:

Both scripts are minimalist queries from documentation that execute a "show tables" or a "select * from table".

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried both connection strings with and without full path. Both scripts are in the same directory as the database.

```php
try {
    $dsn = "firebird:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=DB.FDB;charset=UTF8";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'sysdba', 'password');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$query = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES");
```

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
> error: -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown -
> line 1, column 1 SHOW in /home/user/firebird.php:23

Python 3:

```py
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(
    dsn='localhost:DB.FDB',
    user='sysdba', password='password',
    charset='UTF8' # specify a character set for the connection
)

print(con)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("show tables")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/firebird.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute("show tables;")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 3626, in execute
    self._ps = PreparedStatement(operation, self, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 2253, in __init__
    raise exception_from_status(DatabaseError, self._isc_status,
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 1, column 1\n- show', -104, 335544569)
```

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [How do I get a list of tables from a Firebird database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765586/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-tables-from-a-firebird-database). As an aside, your ISQL connect string uses Firebird Embedded and doesn't connect through the server instance. This can lead to issues with access rights. Use connection string `inet://localhost/DB.FDB` or legacy connection string `localhost:DB.FDB` in ISQL.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW TABLES` is exclusively an ISQL command. It is not supported in DSQL as you can see in [Language Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html).

To get list of tables in DSQL, you should query system tables such as RDB$RELATIONS.

And BTW Firebase and Firebird are two completely different products.